# Added CMS block to contacts page layout XML, but doesn't show up

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, magento-1, ce-1.8.1.0, contact-us

I am trying to add a **CMS static block**, to the **magento 1** contacts page, in the **right column**.

I've tried adding the following to

> app/design/frontend/{client}/{theme}/layout/local.xml

```
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="cms/block" name="contact_stores">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>contact_stores</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

I've also tried **overriding** the `contacts.xml` file and adding:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="cms/block" name="contact_stores">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>contact_stores</block_id></action>
     </block>
</reference>
```

But neither of this show up on the page... **What have I missed?**

Edit: I have now also tried adding a `block` with a `template` as follows:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="page/html" name="product.stores" before="banner.right" as="contact_stores" template="moores/contact_right_block.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and the template has the following:

```
<div class="banner_right">
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact_stores')->toHtml();
?>
</div>
```

This also fails to add anything to the page?

Comment: have you checked the template file to see it is calling for <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>

Comment: The page uses the 2columns-right template. In 2columns-right.phtml, I can see `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>`

Comment: Id suggest rechecking which template it is using try changing it to reference name left see if they have used that template and floated the column to the right

Comment: here you are missing like contact_stores where it is id to be mention ok

Comment: @DavaGordon can confirm it is definitely using the 2column-right template. As this is shown when I turn on template path hints

Comment: @MehulKanjariya not sure what you mean?

Comment: I pasted your code into a dev site and it didnt have any issues went straight in which makes me thing it may be an issue with your theme

Comment: @DavaGordon Hmm.. How odd! I've added other items via the layout files before, so not sure what the issue could be. I've tried grepping the layout files for references relating to 'right' or contact_index_index, and haven't been able to find anything that looks out of place!